# How Can I Add a Content Type to Asset Library Programmatically

Tags: content-type, asset-library

I need to add a content type whenever an Asset Library is provisioned.  How can I do this ?  We have SharePoint 2016 On-Prem

Regards,
Bismarck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the script, change the `$Site, $ListName, $ContentTypeName`:

```
asnp *sharepoint*

$Site = Get-SPSite https://sharepoint.dev.cz
$ListName = "Site Assets"
$ContentTypeName = "Picture"

$Web = $Site.OpenWeb()    
Write-Host "Checking site:" $Web.Title
$docLibrary = $Web.Lists[$ListName]

    if ($docLibrary -ne $null)
    {
        $docLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
        $docLibrary.Update()
        $ctToAdd = $Web.ContentTypes[$ContentTypeName]
        $ct = $docLibrary.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
        Write-Host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $docLibrary.Title
        $docLibrary.Update()
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "The list" $ListName "does not exist in site" $Site.Title
    }
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: I was hoping for something like a List Template ID, because users may provision an Asset Library under a different "Title" (List Name) such as "My Asset Library".  I cannot find a List Template ID for "Asset Library"

Comment: I look at properties and Site Assets library is classic Document Library, ServerTemplate="101" ;BaseTemplate: DocumentLibrary ;TemplateFeatureId: 00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101. So is impossible to filter by DocumentTemplateID here. Site Assets library is different from another Document Library only by name. So you are not able to create Site Asset Libary with different Title, cause this is classic Document Library.

Comment: I was able to create an Asset Library and name it "My Asset Library" However, I think the Template ID is 851.  I will try that and see.

Comment: Try it, I worked with SP2013 and here I have AL like DOcumentLibrary and Images as 851. I find article about it but they wrote about SP2010 and there were lots of differences between 2010 and 2013. Hope it helps. Make it as answer, thanks.

Comment: You are correct. When I ran through the debugger, it reported the List ID as 101 (DocumentLibrary {101}).